# How to get the most recent of a set of date variables in java

Tags: java, compare, max, java.util.date

I have about 8 date variables (java.util.Date) with different variable names. What's the most efficient/best way of choosing the most recent (max) of these dates?

Comment: just once. all date variable values may be different. I'm just trying to find the most recent date efficiently for displaying on a jsp page.

Comment: Is the most recent always the max or do you need to account for future dates?

Comment: the most recent is the max. All dates are past dates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ideally, store them in a collection - this might make sense in terms of your program design anyway. If you have e.g. a List object, you can do:

```
Collections.max(dates);
```

Answer (score 6):

Put them in a List and use `Collections.max`.

Answer (score 4):

`Date` is comparable, so add them all to a list, and use `Collections.max()` to find the greatest (latest) date:

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
dates.add(foo);
dates.add(bar);
... etc
Date latest = Collections.max(list);
```

Actually, if you wanted to get fancy, you could do this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T... items) {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Date latest = MyClass.max(foo, bar, fred);
```

But it will also work for any `Comparable`:

```
Integer biggest = MyClass.max(3, 7, 4, 1);
```

Comment: This is O(N log N), whereas Collections.max is O(N).

Answer (score 4):

Since you're storing all your dates in different variables, you need to do something like the following varargs function and pass all your variables off to it:

```
protected Date getMostRecentDate(Date ... dates) {
    Arrays.sort(dates);
    return myDateArray[dates.length - 1];
}
```

Then you'd call it like so:

```
Date mostRecent = getMostRecentDate(date1, date2, date3 /* etc.*/);
```

Comment: This is not efficient since he only wants to get the maximum once. Sorting takes O(N*logN) while a single max operation is O(N).

Comment: @Tudor sure, though in all fairness, with small N (and i'm assuming that he's got small N b/c otherwise maintaining a whole bunch of different fields is going to be a lot of work), there's not going to be much difference.

Answer (score 1):

Add them all to a collection and then sort it, or add them to a collection that's ordered in the first place, such as PriorityQueue:

```
PriorityQueue<Date> dateQ = new PriorityQueue<Date>();
dateQ.add(someDate);
dateQ.add(anotherDate);
dateQ.add(thirdDate); // etc...
System.out.println("Max date is: " + dateQ.peek());
```

Comment: How does the efficiency of this compare to an implementation with a regular collection?

Comment: Good question.  This should be O(N log N), same as adding it to a list and then sorting.  However, Collections.max (as referenced in several other answers) is O(N) so that's definitely more efficient than my answer.